# Access object array using pointer

Tags: c++, object, pointers

This is my sample program

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class B
{
public:
    int i,j;
};

class A
{
public:
    B b[2];
    A()
    {
        b[0].i = 1;
        b[0].j = 2;
        b[1].i = 3;
        b[1].j = 4;
    }
    B* function()
    {
        return b;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    B* obj = new B();
    obj = a.function();
    return 0;
}
```

I have to get the array of b objects(ie, need all the values, b[0].i, b[0].j,b[1].i and b[1].j)

But when I tried it with this code, only one object is returned.

Comment: How do you know one object is returned?

Comment: What's that `new B()` doing there? All it does is add a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you state in the question is not true. Two objects are indeed returned. Access them with `obj[0]` and `obj[1]`.

I guess you are looking at `obj` under the debugger and the IDE cannot know that you mean for your pointer `obj` to be an array of two objects. So the tooltips will only show the first object, `obj[0]`, or `*obj`. But the other object, `obj[1]` is definitely there.

Add the following line after the call to `a.function`:

```
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", obj[0].i, obj[0].j, obj[1].i, obj[1].j);
```

and you will see this output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

---

Note that there is no point in the line `B* obj = new B();` since you immediately overwrite `obj`. You should do it this way:

```
B* obj = a.function();
```

Your code is also a little dangerous in that you must keep `a` alive at least as long as you are making references to `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
B* function()
        {
          return b;
        }
```

returns the pointer to the first element of array

```
B b[2];
```

which can be dereferenced applying pointer arithmetics and/or operator [].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are actually returning the a pointer to the array b[2]. What you want to do now is to iterate through the items in that pointer. You can print them by adding this lines to you code:

```
A a;
B *obj = a.function();
std::cout << obj[0].i << ", " << obj[0].j << "; " << obj[1].i << ", " << obj[1].j << std::endl;
```

And of course, including iostream at the beginning of your file:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: `B* obj = new B()` is totally unnecessary here, it can be simple `B* obj = a.function()` else there will be memory leak.

Comment: Editted that. Anyway, it was not what he was asking(although it's a valid correction).